# Calculation on InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have an InfluxDB. The IoT device sends the data.
The IoT device sends the time value to the database.
I would like to calculate and store and visualize in Grafana the next send time from the time stamp + time value (sleeptimenow).

```
SHOW FIELD KEYS FROM "sleeptimenow"
name: sleeptimenow
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
value    float

SHOW TAG KEYS FROM "sleeptimenow"
name: sleeptimenow
tagKey
------
location
```

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using?

Comment: InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.7~rc0